# C Regex Pattern not matching when expected

Tags: c, regex

I'm attempting to match an IPv4 address with a regular expression, but I can't seem to get a positive match result from `regexec()` and I can't figure out why. The expression, `^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$`, works fine for this test string on https://regexr.com/. I'm now convinced that this must be a nuance of C of which I'm unfamiliar.

**What am I doing wrong with my regular expression?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main()
{
    char testString[] = "192.168.1.100";
    char pattern[] = "^\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}$";
    regex_t regex;
    int reti = regcomp(&regex, pattern, 0);
    if(reti)
        puts("Error!");
    reti = regexec(&regex, testString, 0, NULL, 0);
    if (!reti){
        puts("It's a match!");
    }else{
       puts("No match found!");
    }
}
```

NOTE: I've tried both `0` and `REG_EXTENDED` for the `cflags` argument in `regcomp()`.

Comment: Then replace `\d` with `[0-9]`. And make sure you do use `REG_EXTENDED`

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew. I looked everywhere and couldn't find an answer. I wouldn't have known to search for "\d does not work but [0-9] does" because I didn't know that was my solution! Thanks again!

Comment: When you title the question as "C Regex Pattern not matching when expected" it won't let others find the solution either. There are a ton of such questions in fact, but it is not possible to find them because of titles like "regex failure in C", "why regex in C does not work", etc.

Comment: The issue is always "which regex package are you using" — because what works and what doesn't depends on the regex package.  There's no one "always right" answer — what is OK using PCRE is not necessarily OK using POSIX `<regex.h>`.  You need to know which regex package you're using so you can find the right man page and hence deduce the correct answer.

Comment: Also note that the regex shown will be happy to accept 999.888.777.666 as a valid IPv4 address.  Restricting the values in a regex may not be worth the effort.  You'd need something along the lines of `([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` for the first term (before the first dot; change the leading `[1-9]` to `[0-9]` for the second, third and fourth terms) or something similar to only accept numbers up to 255, excluding 0 in the leading term.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What would you have chosen to name this question, if you were me, and you were not able to figure out why your regex pattern was legit, but wouldn't work in C?